# Como determinar intercessão entre polígonos?

Tags: c

Como determinar um polígono C que seja intersecção de A e B em C ?

```
#include "TPoligono.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

TPoligono *criaPoligono()
{
    int i;  
    TPoligono *pol = (TPoligono *) malloc(sizeof(TPoligono));
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        TPonto *q;
        q = criaPonto();
        pol->vertice[i] = q;
    }
    pol->tam=3;
    printf("Poligono criado com sucesso\n");        
    return pol;
}

void inserePonto(TPoligono *pol, TPonto *p)
{
    printf("Inserindo ponto\n");
    //acha fim do vetor de vertices


    pol->vertice[pol->tam] = p;

    pol->tam++;
    //coloca NULL na posicao seguinte pra mostrar que era o ultimo vertice
    return;
}

void removePonto(TPoligono *pol, int posic)
{    
    if (pol->tam == 3) {
        printf("Nao posso remover\n");
        return;
    }

    free(pol->vertice[posic]);
    pol->tam--;
    pol->vertice[posic] = pol->vertice[pol->tam];
}
```

Comment: Se um Polígono **A** e um Polígono **B** estão se intersectando, como criar um Polígono **C** que seja a intersecção entre **A** e **B**? É esta a sua pergunta?

Comment: Essa pergunta é para polígono em geral? Ou só para polígono convexo? Para polígono convexo acho que consigo pensar numa solução, mas para côncavo isso dificulta

Comment: Eu mesmo respondi à minha dúvida. Vide minha resposta explicando o porquê de ser polígono convexo

Answer (score 4):

Eu acho razoável assumir que os polígonos em questão são polígonos convexos. Se um dos polígonos for côncavo, a interseção pode ser uma multiplicidade de polígonos:

[image: interseção com polígono côncavo]

Antes de começar a tratar a interseção de polígonos, precisamos tratar de alguns assuntos que são requisitos:

1. conceitos geométricos
2. operações entre vetores
3. pertinência de ponto da reta ao segmento
4. interseção entre retas
5. interseção entre segmentos de retas
6. pertinência de ponto à área interna de triângulo
7. envoltório convexo

Com exceção de [produto vetorial](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_vetorial) (que exige geometria em 3D), todo o resto será definido em torno de [geometria plana](https://www.todamateria.com.br/geometria-plana/).

## Conceitos geométricos

Os seguintes conceitos geométricos são de extrema importância para o caso atual:

1. ponto
2. origem
3. vetor
4. reta
5. semirreta
6. segmento de reta

### Ponto

Num plano, um **ponto** é uma entidade *per si* que existe no plano. Um ponto é identificado no plano por duas coordenadas:

> [image: ponto]

### Origem

A **origem** é um ponto em especial:

> [image: origem]

### Vetor

Um **vetor** é uma entidade que indica a diferença entre dois pontos. Seja um vetor [image: vetor V] a diferença entre [image: ponto A] e [image: ponto B]:

> [image: fórmula de V]

Como [image: delta X] e [image: delta Y] são números reais, temos que, de modo genérico:

> [image: vetor V]

Todo vetor tem, em si, três propriedades que os definem:

1. módulo
2. direção
3. sentido

O módulo é o tamanho do vetor.

A direção é o ângulo que o vetor faz com o eixo [image: x].

O sentido é para qual "lado" do ângulo o vetor está apontando.

Um vetor pode ser operado com números reais, com outros vetores e com pontos, conforme será visto na próxima seção.

Todo ponto [image: P] tem seu equivalente vetorial [image: vetor P] se pegarmos sua diferença com a origem:

> [image: P vetorial]

### Reta

A reta é a entre um ponto e todos os múltiplos de um vetor:

> [image: reta]

A direção da reta é dada pela mesma direção do vetor que a compõe.

Reescrevendo a fórmula acima:

> [image: reta]

Para o caso da direção da reta for não-vertical, sua equação se torna:

> [image: reta]

Para o caso da direção da reta for vertical:

> [image: reta vertical]

Como uma reta é composta por um ponto e um vetor, é possível compô-la também através de dois pontos.

### Semirreta

Uma semirreta é muito semelhante a uma reta, porém ela só se prolonga no sentido do vetor, nunca no sentido oposto.

> [image: semirreta]

Como uma semirreta é composta por um ponto e um vetor, é possível compô-la também através de dois pontos. Diferentemente da reta em que o sentido do vetor não importa, a escolha do ponto base é crucial.

### Segmento de reta

Um segmento de reta é uma parte finita contínua de uma reta. Um segmento sempre é delimitado por dois pontos.

> [image: segmento]

Um segmento entre os pontos [image: A] e [image: B] é a interseção entre duas semirretas de sentidos opostos: a semirreta de [image: A] sentido [image: B] e a semirreta de [image: B] sentido [image: A]. Essa interpretação será crucial mais adiante.

## Operações com vetores

Vou me resumir às seguintes operações com vetores:

1. múltiplos de vetor
2. vetor com ponto
3. vetor adicionado a vetor
4. produto escalar
5. produto vetorial com vetores no plano [image: XY]

### Múltiplos de vetor

Essa é uma operação entre um número real e um vetor, resultando em um vetor. Essa operação resulta em um novo vetor na mesma direção do vetor anterior, porém pode ter seu módulo alterado e, também, seu sentido revertido.

Se for usado um número negativo, o sentido do vetor será alterado. Portanto, [image: inversão].

Todo número não unitário alterará o módulo do vetor. Se se deseja um vetor com a metade do tamanho, deve multiplicar por 0.5; para dobrar o tamanho, multiplica por 2.

### Vetor com ponto

A adição de um vetor a um ponto retorna um ponto. Vindo diretamente da definição de vetor.

> [image: A + AB]

### Vetor adicionado a vetor

Ao compor dois vetor, obtemos um terceiro vetor:

> [image: AB + BC = AC]

Também é derivado da definição de vetor.

### Produto escalar

Essa operação transforma dois vetores em um número real. Mais detalhes para operações generalizadas do produto escalar [neste artigo da Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_escalar).

O produto escalar, em duas dimensões, é dado por:

> [image: V.U]

Um fato interessante é que o produto escalar é diretamente proporcional ao cosseno do ângulo da diferença da direção. Se o produto escalar for negativo, isso significa que o ângulo entre os dois vetores é obtuso; se o produto for zero, o ângulo é reto; se for positivo, é agudo.

### Produto vetorial com vetores no plano XY

O produto vetorial é uma operação entre dois vetores que retorna um novo vetor perpendicular aos dois operandos. Ele só existe em 3 dimensões, veja [este artigo da Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_vetorial) para mais detalhes.

O plano [image: XY], em um espaço tridimensional, é dado pelo conjunto de pontos em que a ordenada [image: Z] é 0. Portanto, a qualquer momento posso abstrair que estamos tratando de geometria plana para a geometria espacial fazendo o truque de adicionar uma ordenada com valor 0 a qualquer ponto (ou vetor).

No caso, usamos o produto vetorial para definir em qual *mão* está a operação de dois vetores. Se fizermos a seguinte operação:

[image: right-handed]

obteremos como resultado um vetor que aponta para cima no eixo [image: Z]. Neste caso, a operação é *destra*. Ao inverter a ordem dos produtos em um produto vetorial, o resultado tem sua *mão* invertida, porém mantém direção e módulo. Neste caso, o resultado apontaria para baixo, sendo portanto uma operação *canhota*.

A fórmula para o produto vetorial, nessas circunstâncias de vetores do plano [image: XY], é dado por:

> [image: A x B]

## Pertinência de ponto da reta ao segmento

Seja um ponto [image: C] pertentencente à reta [image: AB]. Como saber se [image: C] pertence ao segmento [image: AB]?

Uma das possíveis soluções para esse dilema passa pela pergunta sobre a pertinência do ponto a uma semirreta. Através dos conceitos previamente apresentados, se o ponto pertencer à semirreta [image: AB] e à semirreta [image: BA], então ele pertence ao segmento [image: AB].

A seguir, irei responder à pergunta *pertence [image: C] à semirreta [image: AB]?*. Para saber sobre o segmento, é só fazer **também** o análogo para a semirreta [image: BA].

Entre 3 pontos na mesma reta, só existem 2 possibilidades do valor do ângulo entre eles:

1. 0°
2. 180°

Se [image: CAB] for de 0°, isso significa que [image: B] e [image: C] estão no mesmo sentido da reta em relação a [image: A], portanto [image: C] pertence à semirreta [image: AB]. Caso contrário, se [image: C] estiver no sentido oposto a [image: B], o ângulo [image: CAB] será de 180°.

Tá, mas e daí? Como isso pode ajudar?

Simples. Com vetores e produto escalar.

Tome o produto escalar [image: AC . AB]. Se o resultado der positivo, isso significa que o ângulo é agudo, portanto 0°; se der negativo, então o ângulo é 180°.

Daí, se [image: AC . AB] for positivo, então [image: C] pertence à semirreta [image: AB].

## Interseção entre retas

Duas retas podem ter uma das possíveis [três relações](http://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/matematica/posicoes-relativas-duas-retas.htm) em um plano:

1. elas podem ser coincidentes;
2. elas podem ser paralelas não-coincidentes;
3. elas podem ser concorrentes.

Se elas forem coincidentes, elas tem a mesma equação da reta, portanto tem infinitos pontos de coincidência:

> [image: retas coincidentes]

Se elas forem paralelas, temos o mesmo fator de inclinação, porém tem um offset distinto:

> [image: retas paralelas]

E então, para retas concorrentes:

> [image: retas concorrentes]

Estamos interessados agora apenas para o caso de retas concorrentes, retas que se interceptam em apenas um único ponto. Se uma das retas for vertical, trivialmente se acha o valor de [image: X] do ponto de encontro, então se pode achar o valor de [image: Y] utilizando-se do parâmetro [image: X] para a outra reta.

Se ambas as retas forem não-verticais, elas irão se interceptar em um ponto. Para determinar que ponto é esse:

> [image: X da interseção]

Calcular o valor de [image: Y] nesse caso torna-se trivial agora.

## Interseção entre segmentos de retas

Basicamente aqui, basta calcular qual a interseção das retas que compõe os segmentos e verificar se o ponto encontrado pertence a ambos os segmentos.

## Pertinência de ponto à área interna de um triângulo

Dado o triângulo [image: ABC], deseja-se saber se [image: D] está contido na área interna de [image: ABC].

Se [image: D] estiver na mão oposta a [image: C] relativo a [image: AB], então [image: D] está fora do triângulo. Vê-se isso facilmente usando produto vetorial: [image: AB x AC] precisa ter o mesmo sinal de [image: AB x AD].

Uma das formas de garantir que [image: D] está dentro do triângulo é garantir que ele não esteja fora. Para garantir que ele não esteja fora, é preciso verificar a mão dele em relação não somente a [image: AB] como falado acima, mas também a [image: BC] e a [image: CA].

## Envoltório convexo

O envoltório convexo de um conjunto de pontos é o menor polígono convexo que contém todos os pontos desejados. Para maiores detalhes, vide [este artigo da Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envolt%C3%B3ria_convexa).

Tem uma proposta de algoritmo que eu acho que vale a pena falar aqui mesmo, já que é importante para a resposta.

Seja [image: P0] o ponto inicial do envoltório convexo. Para escolher [image: P0], pegue o ponto mais a esquerda (com menor valor possível em [image: X]).

Seja [image: Pi+1] o próximo ponto do envoltório. Para escollher [image: Pi+1], garanta que, para qualquer ponto [image: P] que não pertence aos pontos já inclusos no envoltório, seja destro em relação a [image: Pi] e [image: Pi+1]. Ou seja, [image: Pi Pi+1 x Pi P] precisa ser destro.

Quando não é mais possível selecionar um novo [image: Pi+1], terminamos o envoltório convexo e os vértices do envoltório estarão em ordem.

## Resolvendo o problema

Tome por exemplo a interseção abaixo:

[image: interseção de dois polígonos]

Qual a interseção entre o polígono azul e o preto?

Para saber essa resposta, é necessário encontrar todos os pontos dos polígonos que estão contidos dentro do outro polígono (mostrados na imagem dentro de retângulos vermelhos) e quais são as interseções entre os segmentos dos dois polígonos (mostrados na imagem dentro de elipses vermelhas). Esses dois conjuntos de pontos são os vértices do polígono de interseção.

Além de saber quais são os vértices, é necessário ordená-los. Para tal, detecte qual o envoltório convexo desses pontos.