# Ponto dentro de um polígono

Tags: c, c++, funções

Preciso criar uma função que verifique se um ponto está dentro de um polígono. Pra isso, pesquisei na internet algumas soluções que possam me ajudar. Encontrei uma que parece ser de grande ajuda, mas em uma das funções necessárias para o funcionamento da função principal, houve um erro. A função é a seguinte:

```
// A função checa se o ponto Q está no segmento PR.
bool NoSegmento(Ponto P, Ponto Q, Ponto R)
{
    if (Q.x <= max(P.x, R.x) && Q.x >= min(P.x, R.x) && Q.y <= max(P.y, R.y) 
&& Q.y >= min(P.y, R.y))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Porém, ao compilar, recebo alguns warnings e erros, por exemplo:

```
implicit declaration of function 'max' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
implicit declaration of function 'min' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
undefined reference to `max'|
undefined reference to `min'|
```

Gostaria de saber se as funções MAX e MIN são funções de alguma biblioteca e qual o propósito de se suar o tipo bool para a função.

Comment: Eu falo de pertencimento de ponto a polígono [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198363/64969).

Comment: Sobre o `max`/`min`, [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437484) diz que você precisa declarar essas funções/macros.

Comment: E a sua função `NoSegmento` verifica se o ponto `Q` está dentro do retângulo definido pelos pontos `P` e `R`, o que portanto não se encaixa em pertencimento de polígonos gerais (apenas retângulos paralelos aos eixos). Também não detecta se realmente pertence ao segmento, então o comentário também é enganoso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa função verifica se um `Ponto` está contido dentro da área ocupada por um Retângulo. Os pontos `P` e `R` são as coordenadas de dois vértices opostos desse Retângulo:

[image: retangulo]

Assumindo que `Ponto` seja algo assim:

```
typedef struct _Ponto
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Ponto;
```

Para compilar seu código em `C++`:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool NoRetangulo( Ponto P, Ponto Q, Ponto R )
{
    return( (Q.x <= std::max(P.x, R.x)) && (Q.x >= std::min(P.x, R.x)) &&
            (Q.y <= std::max(P.y, R.y)) && (Q.y >= std::min(P.y, R.y)) );
}
```

Para compilar seu código em `C`:

```
#define max(a,b)  ( (a > b) ? a : b )
#define min(a,b)  ( (a < b) ? a : b )

int NoRetangulo( Ponto P, Ponto Q, Ponto R )
{
    return( (Q.x <= max(P.x, R.x)) && (Q.x >= min(P.x, R.x)) &&
            (Q.y <= max(P.y, R.y)) && (Q.y >= min(P.y, R.y)) );
}
```

Melhorando a ideia (em `C++`):

```
#include <algorithm>


typedef struct Retangulo_
{
    Ponto a;
    Ponto b;
} Retangulo;


int NoRetangulo( Retangulo R, Ponto X )
{
    return( (X.x <= std::max(R.a.x, R.b.x)) && (X.x >= std::min(R.a.x, R.b.x)) &&
            (X.y <= std::max(R.a.y, R.b.y)) && (X.y >= std::min(R.a.y, R.b.y)) );
}
```

Comment: Eu acho estranho que a pergunta fala de polígonos generalizados, mas o resto do contexto aponta para retângulo paralelo aos eixos

Answer (score 1):

[image: Imagem de ponto e vertices]

```
 private void teste()
    {
        double xMax = 0;
        double yMax = 0;
        double xMin = 9999999999999999999;
        double yMin = 9999999999999999999;

        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.PointF> listaDePontos = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.PointF>();
        var p1 = new System.Drawing.PointF(2, 8);
        var p2 = new System.Drawing.PointF(6, 2);
        listaDePontos.Add(p1);
        listaDePontos.Add(p2);


        //Cria uma lista de vertices
        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.PointF> listaDeVertices = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.PointF>();
        var v1 = new System.Drawing.PointF(5, 8);
        var v2 = new System.Drawing.PointF(9, 1);
        var v3 = new System.Drawing.PointF(1, 1);

        listaDeVertices.Add(v1);
        listaDeVertices.Add(v2);
        listaDeVertices.Add(v3);

        //Calcula o mínimo e máximo de X e Y
        for (int i = 0; i < listaDeVertices.Count; i++)
        {
            xMax = Math.Max(xMax, listaDeVertices[i].X);
            yMax = Math.Max(yMax, listaDeVertices[i].Y);

            xMin = Math.Min(xMin, listaDeVertices[i].X);
            yMin = Math.Max(yMin, listaDeVertices[i].Y);
        }



        foreach (PointF p in listaDePontos)
        {
            if (PontoDentroDoPoligono(p, listaDeVertices))
            {
                //to do 
            }
        }
  }

     private bool PontoDentroDoPoligono(System.Drawing.PointF p,
        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.PointF> vertices)
    {
        if (!(p.X >= vertices.Min().X && p.X <= vertices.Max().X && p.Y >= vertices.Min().Y && p.Y <= vertices.Max().Y))
        {
            return false;
        }
        bool result = false;
        int j = vertices.Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((vertices[i].Y < p.Y && vertices[j].Y >= p.Y) || (vertices[j].Y < p.Y && vertices[i].Y >= p.Y))
            {
                if (vertices[i].X + (p.Y - vertices[i].Y) / (vertices[j].Y - vertices[i].Y) * (vertices[j].X - vertices[i].X) < p.X)
                {
                    result = !result;
                }
            }
            j = i;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As funções min e max são da biblioteca **algorithm** do **C++** [veja a referência na documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)

Acrescente no seu código:

```
#import <algorithm>
```

e modifique a sua função para utilizar o namespace std:

```
std::min() e std::max()
```