# Obter/Calular bordas de um objeto 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, matemática, unity-5, geometria

Tenho a seguinte dúvida em relação à obter as posições de uma determinada borda de um objeto 3D.

Exemplo, tenho uma pista (jogo de carros) e quero calcular, através de um script C#, os dois lados da pista. Veja imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho as posições de todos os vértices (que também existem no centro da pista), porém quero os vértices que estão apenas nos limites da pista.

Alguém sabe qual o cálculo devo usar?

Comment: Aparentemente me parece seguro ignorar o eixo Z, ficando apenas com X e Y. Estou certo? Isso diminui muito o que precisa ser buscado, sem falar que eu tenho uma reposta com parte da sua necessidade ([envoltório convexo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198363/64969)). Não é lá o melhor para o seu caso (ignoraria as concavidades das curvas), mas é alguma coisa

Answer (score 0):

Com os dados que forneceste parece-me impossível resolver o problema, no entanto se a pista tiver largura constante (ou conseguires saber a largura da pista num determinado vértice) existe uma solução.

Em cada vértice vais verificar se existe um qualquer outro vértice que se encontre a uma distância de *uma pista*. Segue-se um exemplo:

```
Vertices[] arrayVertices;
float larguraDaPista = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < arrayVertices.size(); i++){
    Vertice verticeATestar = arrayVertices[i];
    for(int j = i; j < arrayVertices.size(); j++){
        Vertice verticeParaComparar = arrayVertices[j];
        if (Vector3.Distance(verticeATestar, verticeParaComparar) == larguraDaPista){
        //São ambos limites
        }
    }
}
```