# Geometria Computacional - Como verificar se duas retas se interceptam apenas na âncora?

Tags: c++, matemática

Bom galera, preciso fazer um programa em **C++** que recebe um ponto **A(x,0)** um ponto **B(x,0)** esse ponto **A** e **B** eles estão no eixo x, sempre com y = 0.

Após receber o ponto **A** e o ponto **B**, tenho que receber um ponto **C(x,y)** e outro **D(x,y)** e verificar se eles se interceptam apenas na âncora... Segue imagem para ficar mais claro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como mostra a imagem acima, os pontos **A** e **B** formam uma reta.. Ai eu vou receber pontos **C(x,y)** e **D(x,y)** e eu preciso fazer um programa para calcular **Se os pontos se interceptam apenas nos pontos A e B**, porém não sei como fazer isso.

**Não estou pedindo código pronto, apenas uma luz de como verifica se dois pontos se interceptam apenas nos pontos A e B...**

Comment: Você não foi claro, mas você quer saber se o triângulo ABC está dentro do ABD ou vice-versa (terceira figura) ou se o que ocorre é que eles se intersectam sem um estar dentro do outro (segunda figura)? Considerando sempre que y>0, obviamente. É isso?

Comment: Você já tentou fazer algum código para fazer isso?

Comment: Eu não consegui, chegar eu uma fórmula.. eu tenho que verificar se um triangulo ABC esta completamente dentro de um triangulo ABD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há quatro conceitos a se considerar:

- Ponto
- Vetor
- Reta
- Triângulo

Todos esses conceitos estão em 2 dimensões. O ponto e o vetor têm uma coordenada `x` e uma coordenada `y`. Um triângulo é representado por 3 pontos.

A reta pode ser representada como um ponto e um vetor ou como dois pontos. Para encontrar o vetor `v` de uma reta dada pelos pontos `a` e `b`, você pode fazer isso:

```
v.x = a.x - b.x;
v.y = a.y - b.y;
```

O caso oposto, para achar o ponto `b` a partir de uma reta com um ponto `a` e um vetor `v` é isso:

```
b.x = a.x - v.x;
b.y = a.y - v.y;
```

Observe que nos dois casos é a mesma equação. De fato, nesse segundo par de equações, você poderia usar `+` ao invés de `-` se preferisse ou então multiplicar `v.x` e `v.y` por um mesmo número qualquer diferente de zero antes de somar ou subtrair com as coordenadas de `a`, pois a única cosa que importa aqui para definir o ponto `b` é que ele seja qualquer ponto sobre a reta desde que não seja o próprio `a`.

Para simplificar alguns cálculos, você pode preferir trabalhar com vetores normalizados. Para criar um `u` normalizado a partir de um vetor `v`, você faz isso:

```
double mag = sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
u.x = v.x / mag;
u.y = v.y / mag;
```

E observe que isso só funciona se pelo menos um entre `v.x` e `v.y` for diferente de zero. Neste seu problema, vetores nulos não são usáveis.

Dito isso, o que você tem que fazer é ver se o ponto D está dentro do triângulo ABC ou se o ponto C está dentro do triângulo ABD. Para isso, você já vai ter uma função mais ou menos assim:

```
bool dentro(Triangulo t, Ponto p);
```

Ou, se estiver usando classes:

```
bool Triangulo::dentro(Ponto p);
```

Agora temos que ver como saber se um ponto está dentro do triângulo. Para fazer isso, podemos ver que uma reta sempre divide o plano em duas partes. Logo, o ponto D está dentro do triângulo ABC se todas essas condições forem verdadeiras:

- Usando A e B para dividir o plano, os pontos C e D estão do mesmo lado.
- Usando A e C para dividir o plano, os pontos B e D estão do mesmo lado.
- Usando B e C para dividir o plano, os pontos A e D estão do mesmo lado.

Se todas as condições acima forem verdadeiras, então D está dentro do triângulo. Se pelo menos uma delas for falsa, está fora. Um ponto em cima da linha pode ser considerado como estando dos dois lados simultaneamente (ou seja, em cima da linha é dentro do triângulo).

Com isso, você terá uma função mais ou menos assim:

```
bool mesmo_lado(Reta r, Ponto p1, Ponto p2);
```

Ou então assim:

```
bool Reta::mesmo_lado(Ponto p1, Ponto p2);
```

Para saber em qual lado da reta um ponto está, você pode fazer algo como na figura abaixo:

[image: Retas]

Nessa figura, os pontos A e B formam uma reta e há um ponto C. Então, existe uma reta CK perpendicular a reta AB (ou seja, formam um ângulo de 90°), onde o ponto K é o ponto onde as duas retas se encontram.

A ideia é você usar um vetor para medir esse segmento CK. Você depois fará o mesmo com D produzindo uma reta DJ (onde J é um outro ponto sobre a reta AB, mas não necessariamente igual a K). Como resultado, CK e DJ serão vetores de mesma direção, mas não necessariamente com os mesmos sentidos. Se CK e DJ tiverem o mesmo sentido, então C e D estão do mesmo lado. Se CK e DJ tiverem sentidos opostos, então C e D estão em lados diferentes da linha AB.

Assim sendo, para encontrar o vetor perpendicular a um outro vetor:

```
Vetor *Vetor::perpendicular() {
    return new Vetor(this.y, -this.x);
}
```

Ou então poderia ser isso também (o vetor apontaria para o lado oposto, mas na mesma direção):

```
Vetor Vetor::perpendicular() {
    return new Vetor(-this.y, this.x);
}
```

Feito isso, você já tem a reta AB e ao usar o ponto C e o vetor perpendicular da reta AB, você consegue a reta CK.

No entanto, você ainda não sabe onde está o ponto K. Para localizá-lo, usamos um sistema de equações, onde os pontos são `a`, `b` e `c`, o vetor da reta AB é `vab`, o vetor perpendicular a `vab` é `vck`, `r` é o comprimento do segmento AK e `s` é o comprimento do segmento CK:

```
k.x = a.x + r * vab.x;
k.x = c.x + s * vck.x;
k.y = a.y + r * vab.y;
k.y = c.y + s * vck.y;
```

Vamos isolar `r` e `s`:

```
r = (k.x - a.x) / vab.x;
r = (k.y - a.y) / vab.y;
s = (k.x - c.x) / vck.x;
s = (k.y - c.y) / vck.y;
```

Observe que há duas fórmulas para o `r` e duas para o `s`. Use a que melhor convir. A que melhor convém é aquela que melhor evita divisão por zero. Assim sendo, você pode comparar `vab.x` e `vab.y` e optar pela fórmula que divide pelo maior. O mesmo ocorre com `vck.x` e `vck.y`.

Encontrando-se o ponto K, você pode criar a reta CK. Você faz o mesmo para D e obtém um ponto DJ onde J é algum outro ponto. Observe que nesse caso, o vetor de CK e de DJ terão a mesma direção. Aí você pode verificar o sentido ao comparar os sinais dos componentes `x` e `y` do vetor. Sinais iguais é mesmo lado e sinais diferentes são lados opostos.

Com isso, você pode finalmente montar a sua função/método `mesmo_lado` e com ele a função/método `dentro` e por fim solucionar o seu problema.

Comment: Eu tratei de outra maneira o pertencimento de ponto à área interna do triângulo, mas no fundo são maneiras equivalentes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198363/64969; a sua abordagem eu achei mais fácil de entender a ideia, mas acho que verificar a "mão" do ângulo é mais fácil

Answer (score 1):

O que vc precisa verificar é se, dados os pontos C e D, o triângulo formado por ABC contem o ponto D OU se o triângulo formado por ABD contem o ponto C. Existe um algoritmo bem eficiente para verificar se um ponto P está dentro de um triângulo ABC, dado a seguir em pseudo-código (acredito que vc não terá dificuldade para traduzir na sua linguagem preferida! ;-D ):

```
Ponto P {
    double x,y;
}

double escalar(Ponto P,Q){
    return P.x*Q.x + P.y*Q.y;
}

bool estaDentro(Ponto A,B,C,  P){
    // vetores AB, AC e AP
    V0.x = B.x-A.x;  V0.y = B.y-A.y;
    V1.x = C.x-A.x;  V1.y = C.y-A.y;
    V2.x = P.x-A.x;  V2.y = P.y-A.y;

    // calcula produtos escalares entre V0, V1 e V2
    P00 = escalar(V0,V0);
    P11 = escalar(V1,V1);
    P01 = escalar(V0,V1);
    P02 = escalar(V0,V2);
    P12 = escalar(V1,V2);

    DIV = P11*P00 - P01*P01;
    U = (P11*P02 - P01*P12) / DIV;
    V = (P00*P12 - P01*P02) / DIV;

    // verifica se ponto está dentro do triângulo
    if (U>=0) AND (V>=0) AND (U+V<1) return true;  // está dentro do triangulo
    else return false; // está fora do triângulo
}
```

E agora, para resolver seu problema:

```
bool apenasNaAncora(Ponto A,B,  C,D){
    return estaDentro(A,B,C,  D) OU
           estaDentro(A,B,D,  C); 
}
```

A ideia aqui é que estou convertendo  a representação do ponto P em coordenadas cartesianas para as coordenadas (U,V) onde U e V são as coordenadas do ponto P usando os vetores AB e AC como bases.

Esta solução é para pontos genéricos. No seu problema, A.y e B.y SEMPRE VALEM ZERO, o que nos permite simplificar um pouco e economizar algumas multiplicações. ;-)

```
bool estaDentroVersao2(Ponto A,B,C,  P){
    V0.x = B.x-A.x;  V0.y = 0;
    V1.x = C.x-A.x;  V1.y = C.y;
    V2.x = P.x-A.x;  V2.y = P.y;

    // calcula produtos escalares entre V0, V1 e V2
    P00 = escalar(V0,V0);
    P11 = escalar(V1,V1);
    P01 = escalar(V0,V1);
    P02 = escalar(V0,V2);
    P12 = escalar(V1,V2);

    DIV = P11*P00 - P01*P01;
    U = (P11*P02 - P01*P12) / DIV;
    V = (P00*P12 - P01*P02) / DIV;

    // verifica se ponto está dentro do triângulo
    if (U>=0) AND (V>=0) AND (U+V<1) return true;  // está dentro do triangulo
    else return false; // está fora do triângulo
}
```

Mas eu ficaria com a versão genérica mesmo, que permite resolver uma gama maior de problemas.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).